# Hi! If u know how to fix a problem try to help me

Tags: plugins, minecraft

I changed from eclipse to Intellij and evertime when Im exporting minecraft plugin i recive this error. I can mark that i changed java version and still doesnt help. Thanks for answers!

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: voxu/main/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 59.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:101) ~[spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:86) ~[spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:64) ~[spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:131) ~[spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        ... 14 more
```

Comment: You're updating the wrong type of Java. You must update the Java _Runtime_ (JDK, I think).

Answer (score 0):

```
voxu/main/Main
has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 59.0),
this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

So the error is a using a newer JRE version when IntelliJ compiles the class files and then a older version when you try to run it.
You can either change your Project SDK to a older version in Project Settings in IntelliJ before compiling, or use a newer JRE when running.

Make sure to [update the JAVA_HOME](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0917/inst_jdk_javahome_t/index.html) environment variable on your system so it knows which JRE to use.

You can see which Java version is installed by opening a terminal and entering:

```
java -version
```